# is 'bookman old style' web safe

Tags: css, web-development, fonts

Is 'Bookman Old Style' web safe? If not, is there something that looks similar which is web safer?

Comment: For the longest time, the list of web safe fonts that I used was [this site's](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html), and it doesn't list bookman.  But ultimately I'm not sure how accurate it is (hasn't been updated in 3 years), so I don't have a good answer for you.

Comment: Have you considered using JavaScript deployed fonts such as those from [Typekit](http://typekit.com/)?

Comment: No, it is definitely not web safe. You might get broader coverage with Garamond, but it isn't universally available, either.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a safe choice: Bookman Old Style is [bundled with MS Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookman_%28typeface%29). That means it's on a lot of machines, but far from 100% coverage. None of my machines, for example, has it.

I would check out services like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) or [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) for a free, usable font that can be embedded into your site, and comes close to Bookman.

Answer (score 3):

Bookman Old Style is **not** a web safe typeface, but you can specify the following CSS font stack to get an 'old style serif' face on many platforms, with plain serif fallbacks:

```
body{  
    font-family: "Calisto MT", "Bookman Old Style", Bookman, "Goudy Old Style", Garamond, "Hoefler Text", "Bitstream Charter", Georgia, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should re-read the *most authoritative page* as it includes Bookman..

> Other options that usually work cross-platform are:
>
> - Palatino
> - Garamond
> - **Bookman**
> - Avant Garde

and a bit down the page continues with

> ***Bookman***
> Bookman, also called **Bookman Old Style.** Not shipped with WinXP. Shipped with MS Office 2000.

Comment: Did you forget to link whatever that authoritative page is?

Comment: @Su' Original question before being migrated contained a link (*named by the OP as the most authoritative page according to google on web fonts..*). to http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html and noted that it does **not** contain the *bookman old style*..

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* have Bookman, it's available under Typekit's [Personal plan](https://typekit.com/plans), which is currently just $25/year. Otherwise, there's nothing stopping you from specifying it in your font stacks; you'll have to decide the likelihood of your audience haaving Office installed, etc. and whether that's worth it. Just make sure you provide a fallback to something more reliable like Georgia.

Comment: +1 Here's [Bookman on Typekit.](http://typekit.com/fonts/bookman)